# Having Difficulty Decoding Swift [Any:Hashable] Dictionary

Tags: swift, struct, enums, nsdictionary, codable

I am very new to Swift and I'm attempting to decode the following dictionary with nested values

```
 ` Data Optional(Dictionary.Keys([AnyHashable("playesOnline")]))
Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x1c421f0b0>(
{
 "_id" =     {
    "$oid" = 5b604f23b48453051501927b;
};
displayName = test;
location =     {
    city = Philadelphia;
    country = US;
    latitide = "39.97669982910156";
    longditute = "-75.25859832763672";
};
online = 1;
userName = test;
}))`
```

I have the following struct

```
import Foundation



struct Player {
   let _id: String
   let displayName:String
   let online: Bool
   let latitide: Double
   let longitude: Double
   let userName : String
   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case _id
       case latitude
       case longitude
       case location
       case online
       case userName
}
```

Any help decoding the above response or any insights on how to subscript the  nested values so I can insert them into an array with $oid,userName,latitude, longitude for each entry would be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: make yourself a favor print your data response from the server `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` and edit your question

Comment: From my experience, it's best if you have a 1-on-1 mapping between the JSON and the Swift `Decodable` type, it's simpler to implement and easier to maintain. BTW, looking at your code seems you missed conforming to `Decodable`.